# Avoid binding the progress bar multiple times in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

There is a situation where I have to bind progress bar value with a property of a class. However there are multiple instances of the class and I do not want to set DataContext multiple times. Is there any way?

Do not want to have this statement in the loop:

```
  progressBarCurrent.DataContext = object;
```

Comment: How about pass the progress bar to setter of your property, and set DataContext there every time your property change?

Comment: `However there are multiple instances of the class` - Can you please clarify? your VM should handle that and let the UI have a single value to bind to.

Comment: do not want the ui element to be passed around, that's why i'm binding its value

Comment: by multiple instances i mean multiple objects(basically there's a loop in which object is reinitialized every time)

Comment: I don't like having to repeat myself. **your VM should handle that and let the UI have a single value to bind to.**

Comment: but the requirement is such that i need the values to be updated in accordance with the state of the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you have having to re-bind or re-set the datacontext on a UI element you probably are just lacking a `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation on some property on one of your VMs.

Instead of setting the datacontext of your `ProgressBar` directly to the object, you should **BIND the DataContext** of the `ProgressBar` to a property on your ViewModel, and then whenever you re-initialize the object you just set that property, which you should have raise a `PropertyChanged` event and the `ProgressBar` will automatically update its DataContext.